# jQuery scroll radio input into div to checked by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, radio-button

I've a DIV (overflow-y:auto;) with some RADIOs input, and a radio checked by default.

How do I scroll automatically to the radio CHECKED?

The DIV is scrollable and shows radio four at a time.. Is it possible to scroll and show automatically radio checked, in the example "SEVEN", by default?

1. ONE
2. TWO
3. THREE
4. FOUR
5. FIVE
6. SIX
7. SEVEN (checked by default)
8. EIGHT
9. NINE

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should give the radio button an id or class , something to identify it with, then
you can do like this :

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#defaultRadio").offset().top //let's say your radio button has id="defaultRadio"
}, 1000);
```

this will do an animation of 1000 milliseconds ( 1 second ) towards your target div

Comment: Thanks,  I try it but not works. My DIV is into a MODAL of Bootstrap 3.

Comment: could you include more code? I responded with what you put in your post

Comment: It's complicated to include the code. It's generated by an ajax request.. then a modal (of bootstrap 3) appears with more radios option.. and a radio of this in by default.

Comment: then make it a function:

`function scrollToDefault(){
$(#myModal .modal-body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#defaultRadio").offset().top
}, 1000);
}
`
then just call `scrollToDefault();` in your ajax success or in the button you click etc..

change the modal id (myModal) according to your preferences